# How to backup and restore Open edX from one server to other?

Tags: openedx

I have an Open edX system run entire in only one server, but system performance is bad. Its RAM consuming is being increased day by day, now I wan to backup and restore to other bigger server.

Document of Open edX is hard to reach this information, and I've searched for a while but don't get what I want. If you know this, please guide me on this problem

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You need to backup **edxapp** and **cs_comments_service_development** database in mongodb and all data from mysql.

Backing up:

```
mysqldump edxapp -u root --single-transaction > backup/backup.sql
mongodump --db edxapp
mongodump --db cs_comments_service_development
```

Restoring:

```
mysql -u root edxapp < backup.sql
mongo edxapp --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
mongorestore dump/
```

It worked for me. Copies all courses, accounts, progress and discussions.

Idea taken from [BluePlanetLife/openedx-server-prep](https://github.com/BluePlanetLife/openedx-server-prep), for more details, look [here](https://github.com/alikhil/open-edx-configuring/blob/master/README.md#backuping-server-and-restoring-it-on-another-machine)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a exact answer also not a standard solution for production environment, but might help you.

Manual way can be as follows:

1. You can setup a new edX instance on a new server.
2. Update all your repos edx-platform, custom xblocks to appropriate branch,tag.

(The database replacement point 3 and 4 below i haven't tested for production environment.)

3. replace the mysql databases 'edxapp', 'ora', 'xqueue' in new server with older ones.
4. replace mongodb databases 'cs_comments_service_development', 'edxapp' in new server with older ones.

   I was able to replace mysql 'edxapp' database on the devstack.